# Is it considered bad style to bring the variants of an enum into scope for its impl?

Tags: rust, enums, scope

Consider the following code:

```rust
enum Foo {
    Var1(String),
    Var2(i32),
}

impl Foo {
    fn bar(&self) -> i32 {
        match self {
            Foo::Var1(_) => 0,
            Foo::Var2(x) => *x,
        }
    }
}
```

Now one might want to make the code look a bit cleaner by bringing the variants of the enum into scope of the impl block like this:

```rust
enum Foo {
    Var1(String),
    Var2(i32),
}

use Foo::*;
impl Foo {
    fn bar(&self) -> i32 {
        match self {
            Var1(_) => 0,
            Var2(x) => *x,
        }
    }
}
```

Is this common among Rustaceans or is this considered bad style?

Comment: Why else would one bring something to the scope? Do what you like. This is too insignificant.

Comment: Please test code you post, yours didn't compile for several reasons :)

Comment: Note that there's no 'best practices' rule that would prohibit having enum members in the global scope. For example, `Ok`, `Err`, `Some` and `None` are enum members exposed by the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of importing it globally (which might clutter the global scope with the enum members) you can put the `use` statement in the local scope. I'd consider this cleaner, but of course it's personal preference.

```rust
enum Foo {
    Var1(String),
    Var2(i32),
}

impl Foo {
    fn bar(&self) -> i32 {
        use Foo::*;
        match self {
            Var1(_) => 0,
            Var2(x) => *x,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way of bringing the enum into scope withhin the entire impl block instead of putting the use Foo::*; in every method?

Comment: Not sure, tbh. But I think it's fine to just do it globally, then. I don't think there is a real best practices thing there. If `cargo clippy` doesn't complain, most programmers won't either, I think.